# check to see if matrix has a root node in java

Tags: java, matrix, root

So i need to check if a matrix has a root node or if its even a tree at all.
the way im doing it is im checking to see if there is exactly one node that has an indegreee of 0 and all other nodes need to be one. i am doing this already, but my code is not checking to see if there are any cycles. I dont know how to check to see if there are any cycles because if there are any, this means the matrix is not a tree.

so if you were to draw a diagraph of the matrix bellow, you would get something like this.

The matrix im testing on is:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here is the code im running it against in a separate file called matrixWork

```
public int rootnode(){
// Root node number (if any) of current matrix
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++){
    if(indegree(i) == 0){
        for(int j = i; j < SIZE-1; j++){
            if(indegree(i) == 0 && indegree(j) !=0){
                return i;   
            }
        }
    }
    else if(indegree(i) > 1)
        return -1;
}
//in case they are all 1s
return -1;
}

public int indegree(int K){
// Number of arrows INTO node K of digraph
// Nodes are numbered 0,1,2,...,SIZE-1
int colsum = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
  colsum = colsum + M[r][K];
return colsum;
}
```

Here is the main class

```
public class MatrixWork{
    // Instance variables
    public int M[][];
    public int SIZE;

    // Boolean matrix constructors

    public MatrixWork(int s){
      SIZE = s;
      M = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
      // Fill M with zeros
      for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++){
          M[r][c] = 0;
        }
      }
} 

  public MatrixWork(int[][] B){
      SIZE = B.length;
      M = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
      // Copy matrix B values into M
      for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++){
          if(B[r][c] == 0)
            M[r][c] = 0;
          else
            M[r][c] = 1;
        }
      }
  } 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int A[][] = new int[][]
        {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

        MatrixWork MA = new MatrixWork(A);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for the mathematical algorithm or for how to implement one?

Comment: What does "matrix is a tree" mean? I have some ideas, but I guess you need to write more than that.

Comment: i need to know how to implement it. and im sorry Naplatny... i means matrix in a tree.. i will go and add more details

Comment: Matrix is a matrix and tree is a tree. You can store tree in a matrix, but you need to define how you represent it.

Comment: Is your matrix tree an [Adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)?

Comment: it is a Boolean Matrix

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future looking for an answer for this kind of question. I was able to to a Transitive closure on the matrix itself. If any number in the diagonal is a 1, it means that there was a cycle, therefore this was not a tree.
Hope this helps anyone else.